# Who is the Mysterious Stranger and how to find him?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I had an obiective saying that I needed to find the Mysterious Stranger several times (4, if I remember right), in exchange for a Pet Cage.
But, **how can I find him?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mysterious Stranger is a character in Fallout Shelter who will at random spawn throughout your shelter in random places at random times. You will see him quite distinctly because of how much he stand out. He looks like this.[image]
When clicked on he will give you caps and your objective will be cleared. You will find him in one of your Shelter's rooms randomly. Hope this helped.